# Errors while trying to install gitolite

Tags: centos, repository, git, gitolite

I'm trying to get up and running gitolite as the instructions said at this http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/qi.html but when I run the command:

```
[git@devserver gitolite]$ src/gitolite install -ln
FATAL: errors found before logfile could be created
FATAL: die  unknown gitolite sub-command
```

I get the errors above, what I'm doing wrong? I create the git user as:

```
useradd -d /data/gitrepos git
```

And then cd to /data/gitrepos and clone the gitolite repo with the following command:

```
git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
```

Any advice? Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the sources of [gitolite `install`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/install):

> Simplest use, if `$HOME/bin` exists and is in `$PATH`, is:

```
git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
gitolite/install -ln
```

So make sure your  `$HOME/bin` exists *and* is in `$PATH`.

Comment: Hi, @vonc $HOME/bin doesn't exists but /bin yes. So if the directory, $HOME/bin not exists, what will be the next step?  Run the command gitolite setup -pk /path/to/YourName.pub? I'm a bit lost here!

Comment: @ReynierPM is it possible for you to create $HOME/bin? I always prefer a local installation to a system (owned by root) installation.

Comment: yes it's possible in fact I create the $HOME/bin directory and now I've installed and thanks for your support. Now I need to learn git a bit ;)